# Error en JasPerReport al recibir ruta

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy realizando un reporte con una view (vista) de mysql, cuando ingresa a la clase de reportes da error  en la siguiente linea donde me da el error.

```
jr = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(archivo);
```

El error es.

> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the Payara Server 4.1.2.181 #badassfish logs.

y mi codigo es asi nose que estoy haciendo mal :(

```
  public void crearReporteUsuarios() {
        try {
            conn = cn.getConexion();

            // src\\java\\Reportes\\rptUsuarios.jasper
            // Reportes\\rptUsuarios.jasper

            URL archivo = this.getClass().getResource("/Reportes/rptUsuarios.jasper");
            JasperReport jr = null;

            jr = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(archivo);


            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);

            JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jp);
            view.setVisible(true);

            //==================
//            File reportFile = new File("Reportes/rptUsuarios.jasper");
//            Map prm = new HashMap<>();
//            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), prm, conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Como lo indica el mensaje de error que muestras, ¿has podido ver algo más en detalle en otros logs del servidor?

Comment: No la verdad no encontrado mas sobre este error? incluso lo estoy haciendo en netbeans 8.2 y en netbenas 11.3 y me da el mismo error, con tomcat 8 con GlassFish 8 y Payara 5 da el mismo error